# How to get rid of automatic generated ID firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi am new to android firebase and am stuck in middle the problem is when I push new data to database, am getting a new ID as root of one of the child.
[image]

In the screenshot there is a ID below clinic, i want to get rid of it
[image]

I want my data to get added in this manner, like every time when I add new clinic it should get added below general.

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("clinic").push();
```

I have just attached push() at the end of my database reference.

```
myRef.child(typ).child(userID).child("clinic_name").setValue(name);

myRef.child(typ).child(userID).child("total_docs").setValue(total_docs);

myRef.child(typ).child(userID).child("working_hrs").setValue(clinic_wrk_hrs);
```

And in this way I am adding data to data. The only thing I want is get rid of that weird looking extra ID. How I do it?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. It'll also allow you to show us precisely what JSON you want your code to output.

Answer (score 3):

That id is not an automatic generated ID is an id that is pushed by the `push()` method. To get rid of that, you need not to use the `push` method. You need to change this line of code:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("clinic").push();
```

with

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("clinic");
```

Comment: But if i remove push() method then I cannot add new Clinic to general node instead the same clinic will be updated. #Alex Mamo

Comment: In this case you need to keep it. Your question was to how to get rid of that generated id. You cannot remove that id and have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the autogenerated key just remove the push command..like below

```
mRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("clinic");
mRef.child("timestamp").setValue(clinic_address);
mRef.child("timestamp").setValue(clinic_name);
```

If it worked let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never:

I was facing the same issue and I believe what you want to use is `child.update or child.set` as opposed to `child.push`.

Here is an example using the Python SDK `firebase_admin`

```py
root = db.reference(path='/', app=app)  # app was previously created

# PUSH
root.child(test).push({'name': 'John'})
# Will create something like
# ./
# |--test
# |------FIREBASE_ID
# |-----------------name: "John"

# UPDATE / SET
root.child(test).update({'name': 'John'})  # or .set({...})
# Will create something like
# ./
# |--test
# |------name: "John"
```